# Isotope implementation in Wordpress not working on initial load

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

Using this plugin to implement a Isotope style layout: http://mintthemes.com/plugins/isotope-for-wordpress/

On initial load, it all sits in the left hand column and it's overlapping. It works fine as soon as I click on one of the filtering options. Does anyone have any idea how to fix the initial load layout? Any help would be appreciated.

http://www.bigideaadv.com/big_idea_v2/posts/

Here's the JS code:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($) {
    //isotope
    //$(window).load(function() {
        $('.moveplugins_isotopes_container').isotope({
            // options
            itemSelector : '.hentry',
            layoutMode : 'masonry'
        });
    //});
    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('.isotopenav').change(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('value');
        $('.moveplugins_isotopes_container').isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('.isotopenav a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('valuemint');
        $('.moveplugins_isotopes_container').isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Replace `ready` with `load` in the first line? It looks like you've half changed a document.ready declaration